# If .. else number is smaller than, unreachable code

Tags: c, conditional-statements

Let's say we have the following code in C (or similar language):

```
if (x < 10)
  do_work1();
else if (x < 5)
  do_work2();
```

Will the second branch of this conditional be executed in some cases? Will the compiler warn about unreachable code?

Comment: No, it won't be executed. Most ides warn about unreachable code.

Comment: A similar language could overload `>` and have it do the unexpected thing.

Comment: Another situation I can think of where the second branch is executed is if `x` is a global variable and you have another thread that could change the value of `x` that initially was larger than 10 to a value smaller than 5 after the first test in a unlucky circumstance. e.g. `x` is 11 at the beginning. Thread1 makes the first test `if (x < 10)` which is false and after that, Thread2 changes the value of `x` to 4.

Comment: For example, if `x` is a volatile and is changed *after* the `if` part but *before* the `else if` part, then it's possible that else part will be executed in some cases. Asynchronous change like this is a bit outrageous to think of but certainly possible.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Of course, if you do that, all your co-workers will be ready to strangle you...

Answer (score 21):

`Will the second branch of condition be executed in some case?`

- Yes, it could be possible, it depends on what else is going on in the code and what the compiler chooses to do with your code.

`Shouldn't compiler warn about unreachable code?`

- No, it can't because there's no guarantee that it's unreachable

Take this for example:

```
int x = 11;

void* change_x(){
   while(1)
      x = 3;
}

int main(void) 
{
    pthread_t cxt;
    int y = 0;
    pthread_create(&cxt, NULL, change_x, NULL);
    while(1){
        if(x < 10)
            printf("x is less than ten!\n");
        else if (x < 5){
            printf("x is less than 5!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if(y == 0){    // The check for y is only in here so we don't kill
                            // ourselves reading "x is greater than 10" while waiting
                            // for the race condition
            printf("x is greater than 10!\n");
            y = 1;
        }
        x = 11;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
mike@linux-4puc:~> ./a.out 
x is greater than 10!
x is less than 5!      <-- Look, we hit the "unreachable code"
```

Comment: @halex - You made an excellent point and it deserved to be exemplified. And I had a few minutes to spare :)

Comment: Absent any `volatile` attribute (for pre-C11 compilers) or memory barriers, the compiler does not have to worry about `printf("x is less than 5!\n");` and will indeed optimize `main()` into object code that does not even contain the statement, thereby showing you how much it cares about the statement being possibly reachable. The reason the compiler does not warn is NOT that “there's no guarantee it's unreachable”, because it is unreachable for defined executions, and the compiler only cares about defined executions.

Comment: From C11's section J.2 Undefined behavior: “The execution of a program contains a data race (5.1.2.4).”

Comment: Nice example. That is what I wanted to hear... Thank you

Comment: @PascalCuoq - I guess I look at this the same way but with different semantics. "I do not guarantee you will hit that code", means you may, or may not, hit it... ie. it's impossible to say if the code is reachable. "Undefined behavior" is the same thing, it's impossible to say what will happen, or in this instance if the code is reachable. I can update how I phrased that, but I feel the meaning was (or was meant to be) the same

Answer (score 4):

- If x is a local variable then I don't see any way that `do_work2` could be executed.
- If x is a global variable or is shared between multiple threads then `do_work2` could be executed.

It is not possible to prove in general whether or not code is reachable. The compiler can have some simple, understandable and fast-to-check rules that can detect simple cases of unreachable code. It should not include a slow and complex solving system that only *sometimes* works.

If you want extra checking then use an external tool.

Answer (score 1):

The second branch will not be executed and the compiler shouldn't warn about unreachable code.

Comment: `The second branch will not be executed`, Are you sure you want to state that so unconditionally? That code snippet OP gave isn't enought to say for sure it won't be executed

Answer (score 1):

No the compiler won't generate any warning(code unreachable) for this code. this kind of warning come normally when you use return  without any condition.

like

```
int function(){

int x;
return 0;
x=35;
}
```

In this case it will give you warning.

Comment: What is "the compiler"? Several of my compilers do warn against the second line: "code has no affect"/"unreachable code". But of course they don't _have_ to warn, the very definition of a warning is: something that is most likely an error but doesn't violate the C standard.